# SSIS Lookup Task finds no match

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

in the DataFlow-Task of an SSIS-Package I have a Flat-File-Source. The text in this file is encoded as UTF-8.

When I am using a lookup task to check a dimension table in the database, I get no match for text with special characters. The lookup task finds matches for many rows, but not for those with characters like "ü,ä,ö...". This is not corret, because there are rows in the table, so it should match.

What I've done so is, using a convert-task and convert the string from UTF-8 to Windows ANSI - Codepage 1252 with the exact same string length as the column in the Dimension table. The column in the dimension table has the collation "Latin1_General_CI_AS". I've also set the DefaulCodepage-Property of the lookup-task to 1252.

Does everyone know, what I did miss to do?
Thanks.

Comment: I've found a solution myself. In the flat file source I have to use the datatype Unicode string [DT_WSTR] and now the convert-task works fine also the lookup.